# UTF-8 encoding problem with servlet and apache HttpClient

Tags: java, apache, servlets, utf-8, httpclient

I have a servlet that sends a string with utf-8 encoding. Also I have a client written with apache httpcomponents library.

My problem is reading the response in utf-8. Some special characters like ñ or ç are not read correctly. If I test the server with an html page sending a request, the string is correct and the encoding is UTF-8 without BOM.

Some snippets:
**Servlet**

```
response.setContentType ("application/json; charset=UTF-8");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter ();
out.write (string);
```

**Client**

```
entity = response.getEntity ();
entity.getContentEncoding (); //returns null
resultado = EntityUtils.toString (entity, HTTP.UTF_8); //Some characters are wrong
```

Has anyone had the same problem?

SOLVED:
Sorry guys the client and server were working correctly. I'm writting an android app and it seems that the logcat (where I print the messages) doesn't support utf-8 encoding.

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried

```
response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
```

instead of setting the encoding via `setContentType`? It shouldn't make a difference according to the documentation, but who knows...

Also, make sure you didn't call `response.getWriter()` anywhere in your code before setting the character encoding, because the latter would not have any effect in that case.

Comment: Can you identify whether the problem is on the servlet side or on the client side?

Comment: Yeah you should check it out with something like Wireshark.

Comment: I've also tested the connection with wireshark and I've seen that the special characters are sended incorrectly, but firefox shows it correctly :S. Tested with setCharacterEncoding and text/plain content-type but still fails.

Comment: You are right there was no any differences adding or not adding response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8") after setting contentType with charset information. But when I changed the position of calling response.getWriter() immediately worked perfect. Many thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure stream bytes are in UTF-8 format:

```
out.write((yourstring.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

Answer (score 5):

StandardCharsets.UTF_8 can be used with EntityUtil to get the proper encoding.

Here is a sample snippet:

```
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
String webpage = EntityUtils.toString(entity, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've got a similar problem that i solved by using UTF-8 encoding as following:

```
IOUtils.toString(response.getEntity().getContent(), Charsets.UTF_8)
```

Namespace:

```
import com.google.common.base.Charsets;
```